# How do I get the this program to read what the person type as a string and see if the strings are equal?

Tags: c++

I need help ... How do I get the this program to read what the person type as a string and see if the strings are equal?

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            char name;
            cout << "Type my name is:";
            cin >> name;
            if
               name ==char('Mike') //this is where i think the problem is...
                cout << "congrats";
            else
            cout << "Try again";
        }
```

Comment: Ouch, that's a really unfortunate valid syntax (or it wold be if the `if` had brackets, and braces would help, too). Just use a `std::string` and compare it like anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using std::string in c++?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string name;
        cout << "Type my name is:";
        cin >> name;
        if (name == "Mike"))
            cout << "congrats";
        else
            cout << "Try again";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Type my name is:";
    std::cin >> name;
    if (name == "Mike") // Compare directly to the string "Mike"...
        std::cout << "congrats";
    else
        std::cout << "Try again";
}
```

I think it is always better habit to use `std::` instead of `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `char` is a character variable, not a character array. If you want to create a 'c-string' (collection of characters), use `char name[20]`. To create a string object, use `string name`. Don't forget to `#include <string>`. Here's a brief tutorial for strings:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

If you want to use c-strings, you have to use `strcmp(name,"Mike")` to compare two strings. It returns true if two strings are DIFFERENT, so be careful.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[20];
    cout << "Type my name is:";
    cin >> name;
    if (!strcmp(name,"Mike")) //C string equality tester
        cout << "congrats";
    else
        cout << "Try again";
}
```

Strings are easier to use because you can just use the equality operator `==`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Type my name is:";
    cin >> name;
    if (name == "Mike") //Tests for equality using strings
        cout << "congrats";
    else
        cout << "Try again";
}
```

Also, watch your quotation marks. Single quotes (`'a'`) are for characters, double quotes (`"Mike"`) are for character arrays (words, sentences, etc.)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily return `true`. It returns a number greater than zero or less than zero if the first string is greater or less, respectively, than the second. C++ strings, apart from being easier to use, also won't open up the program to a buffer overflow when the user inputs 20+ characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
  string name;
  string myname("Mike");
  cout << "Type my name is:";
  cin >> name;
  if(name ==myname) //this is where i think the problem is...
  { 
    cout << "congrats";
  }
  else
    cout << "Try again";
}
```

This should do it. But I'm sure you don't want to hard-code "Mike" ONLY. A good improvement would be to get names from a file and then compare. Also keep in mind that string == operator is case sensitive so "Mike" != "mike"

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a single character, replace all your `char` with `std::string` and add `#include <string>` to the beginning of you code. `std::string` will save arbitrary length strings.

`if` is followed by braces: `if(...)`. In your case `if(name == char('Mike'))` or with the advice from above `if(name == std::string('Mike'))`.

In C and C++ the two quotes `'` and `"` are different. You use `'` for single characters and `"` for strings. So it needs to be `if(name == std::string("Mike"))`.

You may also write `if(name == "Mike")`.

Also you should make brackets to increase readability and avoid errors. After `if(...)` you would usually use `{}` to encapsulate the instructions to be executed if the condition in `if(...)` is met. Your case is special, because the brackets may be left out for single instructions.

```
if(...)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```